# Does HashMap gives output in the same order as the order in which the data is added to it?

Tags: java

```
HashMap<String, Point[]> values = new HashMap<String, Point[]>();
values.put(JobPriority.HIGH.toString(), high.toArray(points));
values.put(JobPriority.NORMAL.toString(), high.toArray(points));
values.put(JobPriority.LOW.toString(), high.toArray(points));
values.put(JobPriority.VERYLOW.toString(), high.toArray(points));
```

System.out.println(values);

Comment: No. Consider using a `LinkedHashMap` then.

Comment: As per the documentation: "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

Comment: So easy to test this...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Even easier to google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This implementation provides all of 
>   the optional map operations, and
>   permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly
>   equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits
>   nulls.) **This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map**;
>   in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain
>   constant over time.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

By default, iterators of a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) will return its key and entries in insertion order. A simple `HashMap` will not.

Comment: With `accessOrder` set to `false`.